# split on delimeter and ignore a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I would like to split a string based on a delimiter and ignore a particular pattern.  I have lines in a text file that look like so

```
 "ABC | 0 | 567 | my name is | however
  TQD | 0 | 567 | my name is | but
  GED | 0 | 567 | my name is | haha"""
```

I would like to split on "|" but ignore 0 and 567 and grab the rest.  i.e

```
['ABC', 'my name is', 'however']
['TQD', 'my name is', 'but']
['GED', 'my name is', 'haha']
```

whenever I split, its grabbing the two numbers as well.  now numbers can occur in other places,  but this particular pattern of |0|567| needs to be ignored.  I can obviously split on "|" and pop the element at index 1 and 2.  but looking for a better way.

I tried this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\|(?!0|567)')
pattern.split(line)
```

this yields `[ABC|0|567, my name is, however]`

Comment: Do you want to split on any digit between? See if [this demo](https://tio.run/##LU3LCsIwELznK5ZemkQpgqhQENH@hpeiC13Ii@2iFPrvcQse5gUzTFlkyulYK8WSWYDRmEAJ4QrN/THACgfF6XxRjgukMSLQrGHKX/wgN8aUUQQ56YKxe@VYKKDlFvxztbde5b3bvPPgW6d1piRWq3MJJPa/3sP26lytPw) helps.

Comment: no i want to keep other numbers that occur in string as it is. so my string is like this: 
""ABC|0|567|my name is| however | 222 | 1.000 | etc.

Comment: i want to keep the other numbers but just ignore |0|567 @bobble bubble
so i would like ["ABC", "my name is", "222", 1.000, etc"]
the numbers 0 and 567 occur at the same place and no where else.

Comment: Maybe [this updated demo](https://tio.run/##LY7LCsJADEX38xWhm84MItWiBUFE/Q03RQINdB6kQSnMv48puLgHEjiXm1eZUuxrpZATCzAaM1NEuEJzfzyhQKc5nQdlWCGOAYEWPQ7HXjmlL36QG2PyKIIc1WPcv1PINKPlFvyr2NsFvKIr2uO2j/PgW6cSUxSrwpJnEvvv2MG2wLlafw) works for you.

Comment: yep that works, thank you. can you post this as answer and i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include the `|` specific numbers `|` in the split sequence:

```
pattern = re.compile(r' *\|(?: *(?:0|567) *\|)* *')
```

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I0WQQs/1) or a [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##LY7LCsJADEX38xWhm84MItWiBUFE/Q03RQINdB6kQSnMv48puLgHEjiXm1eZUuxrpZATCzAaM1NEuEJzfzyhQKc5nQdlWCGOAYEWPQ7HXjmlL36QG2PyKIIc1WPcv1PINKPlFvyr2NsFvKIr2uO2j/PgW6cSUxSrwpJnEvvv2MG2wLlafw)

---

The `(?:` [non capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) `)`  is repeated [`*` any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of times.

Comment: hello, i have another question.  I want to ignore the string "US" in there on the first occurance but keep other "US" i.e ABC | 0 | 567 | my name is | however|US|but|no|well|US
and the result is [ABC, my name is, however, but, no, well, US] how do i do that using this?

Comment: @turtle_in_mind Probably easier to remove the first `US` from the string before splitting using `re.sub`: [`line  = re.sub(r"(\||^) *US *\| *", r"\1", line, 1);`](https://tio.run/##LY7NasQwDITvfgrhHtY2S9mltIWWUto@QsgtFJKgsAb/ITu7LPjdU5n0oBEjxDeT7uUSw9O2WZ8iFSAUwtmA8AHy6/sHKpx4nl9eWf0dwugRbGZziTe8ItW@q9Naaoj1hs6xlUI8MMbHK8JiKReI87wSYZgR4gJ9twdwAuFjXidFUg21/mowfQdmqGDkEUgOZ17t9Qhn/d6oOTlbYMww4RK5aRpLQQo7aY4@WYeKDo2hPt/AsJwqd9ftog2YgxaJbCiqJTeY@kfsQVpv2x8)